# Why LSTM give different output despite I use the same code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I ran code from this [link](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Predict-Stock-Prices-Easily-Demo)(for predict price of sp500) and I found that output (predicted price) are not the same when I ran the code for second and third time. They are not even close sometimes. I just know the basic knowledge of LSTM and never code it before.

Comment: Training a network typically involves a lot of randomness - different starting conditions, order of seeing the data, etc. can all significantly affect the results. If you manually seed the randomness (which might include Python's ```random``` module, ```numpy```'s random, and other libraries' random seeds), you should see the same results each run.

Comment: @peerigon Actually, I don't understand the code. I just understand lstm basic. Could you give me a way to learn lstm coding in python. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Google "LSTM Python", and you'll see lots to play with. For example: https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/11/15/anyone-can-code-lstm/  But if you're not comfortable in Python, I recommend you first work through the official Python tutorial. If you want help understanding this specific code, you'll need to start by putting small parts of the code into your answer and clarifying your question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE].

Comment: add this line, before variable declaration and initialization:         'tf.set_random_seed(1)' . And run it multiple times, you will get same results.

Comment: @Pramod Patil Do I have to install tf library first? Can you explain more detail about this. And what does this command do?

Comment: @KornTawe tf is tensorflow. import tensorflow as tf

Answer (score 0):

It is better to seed the inbuilt pseudo-random number generator. Kindly try using the following:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import set_random_seed

random.seed(10)

np.random.seed(10)

set_random_seed(10)
```